# Where to return a created XHR object

Tags: javascript

Found the following function in a textbook. It is supposed to create the latest version XHR object possible.

```
function createXHR(){
    if (typeof arguments.callee.activeXString != "string"){
        var versions = ["MSXML2.XMLHttp.6.0","MSXML2.XMLHttp.3.0","MSXML2.XMLHttp"], 
        i, len;

        for(i=0, len=versions.length; i<len; i++){
            try {
                new ActiveXObject(versions[i]);
                arguments.callee.activeXString=versions[i];
                break;
            }catch(ex){
                //skip
            }
        }

    }
    return new ActiveXObject(arguments.callee.activeXString);
}
```

My question is: why can't we just return the object inside of the for-loop? Something like this:

```
function createXHR(){
    if (typeof arguments.callee.activeXString != "string"){
        var versions = ["MSXML2.XMLHttp.6.0","MSXML2.XMLHttp.3.0","MSXML2.XMLHttp"], 
        i, len;

        for(i=0, len=versions.length; i<len; i++){
            try {
                arguments.callee.activeXString=versions[i];
                return new ActiveXObject(versions[i]);
            }catch(ex){
                arguments.callee.activeXString = undefined;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

These two seem equivalent to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why can't we just return the object inside of the for-loop?

You certainly could. (The `break;` is unnecessary in your second example.)

However, you need to allow for the *second*, third, etc. call to `createXHR`, which your current second code block doesn't. In the case where you *already* have the `activeXString` (e.g., an `else`), you need to do `new ActiveXObject(arguments.callee.activeXString)`.

I'd also suggest throwing an error if none of them work.

---

Note that this is all obsolete and IE-only, though. The correct way to create an XHR object is: `new XMLHttpRequest(...)` Only if `XMLHttpRequest` doesn't exist would you look to fall back on these obsolete ways of doing it (e.g., if you need to support IE8 or IE9-IE11 in their broken "compatibility mode").

Another note: Using `arguments.callee` was always unnecessary in that code, and it no longer works in strict mode (and strict mode is something you want to use). Instead, just use `createXHR`: `createXHR.activeXString = ...`

So for instance:

```
function createXHR() {
    if (typeof XMLHttpRequest !== "undefined") {
        return new XMLHttpRequest;
    }
    // Obsolete-IE-only fallbacks
    if (typeof createXHR.activeXString != "string") {
        var versions = ["MSXML2.XMLHttp.6.0","MSXML2.XMLHttp.3.0","MSXML2.XMLHttp"], 
            i, len;

        for (i = 0, len = versions.length; i < len; i++) {
            try {
                createXHR.activeXString = versions[i];
                return new ActiveXObject(versions[i]);
            } catch (ex) {
                createXHR.activeXString = undefined;
            }
        }

        throw new Error("No XHR available");
    } else {
        return new ActiveXObject(createXHR.activeXString);
    }
}
```

Comment: Removed the `break;` in the second example.

Comment: @Sandi: There was a second issue, I've updated the answer to mention it.

Comment: Thanks for a very detailed answer.

A further question: In your added else clause, there is no handling of the exception that would occur if `new ActiveXObject(createXHR.activeXString);` would throw one. Why not?

Comment: @Sandi: FYI re your edit, there are no typos above. `!==` is the non-coercing "not equals" operator (in this case it doesn't matter whether you use `!=` or `!==`), and parens are optional on `new` expressions if there are no arguments to pass.